# please help me solve this question about cubic graphs and their intersection points

Tags: cubics

I was practicing some maths from the UKMT website's mentoring scheme sheets and I found this question on the sample for sheet 9:

On the same axes, sketch the graphs

$y=(x+1)^3-(x+1)$

$y^2=(x+1)^3-(x+1)$

I also have to identify the points where the graphs intersect.

I found that $(x+1)^3-(x+1) = x(x+1)(x+2)$

From there I found three intersection points: $(0,0), (-1,0)$ and $(-2,0)$

I need to solve $x(x+1)(x+2) = 1$ for another intersection point, but I cant think of any ways to solve it. I was also had no idea on how to sketch a graph for $y^2 = (x+1)^3 - (x+1)$

Comment: Oh I get how to do the graph now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be solved easily?
$$(x+1)^3-(x+1)-1=x^3+3x^2+2x-1$$
The cubic has no rational roots, so there is no simple expression for the $x$-coordinate of the fourth intersection (although *some* exact expression can be written down). The $x$-coordinate is about $0.324717957\dots$, but the $y$-coordinate is just $1$.

Comment: The pdf has no answers attached so I guess It was probably asking for an aproximation as it was a non calculator paper. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @ChrisDaniel You have enough reputation to upvote my answer. Please do that here – it helps all of us.